# Sort array full of ISO dates using Moment js

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ecmascript-6, momentjs

I am trying to sort an array of ISO dates.

```
arr = ["2019-12-30T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-01-06T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-01-13T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-01-20T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-01-27T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-02-03T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-02-10T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-02-17T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-02-24T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-03-02T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-03-09T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-03-16T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-03-23T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-03-30T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-04-06T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-04-13T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-04-20T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-04-27T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-05-04T00:00:00.000Z"]
```

I am trying to sort grouped data using:

```
for (a in get_grouped) {
            cat.forEach(t => {
                if (!get_grouped[a].some(v => v.type == t)) {
                    get_grouped[a].push({
        "date": get_grouped[a][0].date,
        "metric": 0,
        "type": t
      });
    }
  });
  get_grouped[a].sort((a, b) => arr.indexOf(a.date)-arr.indexOf(b.date));
}
```

get_grouped:

```
    (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {date: "2020-01-01", metric: 32, type: "Google"}
1: {date: "2020-01-01", metric: 24, type: "Bing"}
2: {date: "2020-01-01", metric: 0, type: "Jeeves"}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
(index):98 
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {date: "2020-01-02", metric: 1, type: "Google"}
1: {date: "2020-01-02", metric: 0, type: "Bing"}
2: {date: "2020-01-02", metric: 32, type: "Jeeves"}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
(index):98 
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {date: "2020-01-03", metric: 30, type: "Google"}
1: {date: "2020-01-03", metric: 24, type: "Bing"}
2: {date: "2020-01-03", metric: 0, type: "Jeeves"}
```

This sorting works fine with `cat` is an array of strings. How do I sort it when its an array of ISO dates as I showed above? How do I do it using Moment JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By having [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) strings, you could take the standard approach with [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), which sorts by string.

```js
var array = ["2019-12-30T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-01-06T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-01-13T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-01-20T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-01-27T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-02-03T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-02-10T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-02-17T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-02-24T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-03-02T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-03-09T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-03-16T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-03-23T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-03-30T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-04-06T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-04-13T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-04-20T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-04-27T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-05-04T00:00:00.000Z"]

array.sort();

console.log(array);
```

For sorting by the indic of a given date array, you could take an object with a format which matches the data structure for sorting and take the index as value for sorting.

```js
var array = ["2019-12-30T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-01-06T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-01-13T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-01-20T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-01-27T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-02-03T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-02-10T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-02-17T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-02-24T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-03-02T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-03-09T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-03-16T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-03-23T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-03-30T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-04-06T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-04-13T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-04-20T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-04-27T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-05-04T00:00:00.000Z"],
    indices = array.reduce((r, d, i) => (r[d.slice(0, 10)] = i + 1, r), {});

console.log(indices);

// for sorting take
// get_grouped[a].sort((a, b) => indices[a.date] - indices[b.date]);
```

Comment: You should mention the limitations of this approach. It does not work universally.

Comment: How do I go it in context of this: `get_grouped[a].sort((a, b) => cat.indexOf(a.type)-cat.indexOf(b.type));`. This is where the grouping isn't happening?

Comment: please add some examples of `cat` and `get_grouped[[a]` to the question.

Comment: I have added it to the question. `cat` is the same as `arr`. Sorry that was my bad

Comment: great, please see edit with an object for the indices.